# Looping inside a text

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following text:

I would like to achieve the following.

Create a dictionary with keys word1, ... (the ones on the left) 
Then I would like to associate word1 with word7 and, in this case, with word 11 (and add also repetitions) so

```
word1 = [word7, word11, word11]
```

I would like to do this for each word on the left, provided that it is different from the previous already computed.

I have tried with the following, but it does not work:

```
from collections import defaultdict


inputfile = open("file.txt","r")
keys  = []
key = ''

my_dict = defaultdict(list)

for line in inputfile:
    l=line.split()
    a= l[4].split("-")
    b_temp = l[7].rstrip("\'")
    b = b_temp.split("-")
    for elem in range(len(a)):
        if a not in keys:
            keys.append(a)
            key = a[elem]
            my_dict[key].append(b[elem])
            continue
        for var in range(len(a)):
            if a[var] == a[elem]:
                my_dict[key].append(b[var])
```

I know that the number of words on left is equal to the number of words on the right.

For instance, I get something like defaultdict(, {'aaaa': ["'word7", 'word10']})

But I would like

In this case

word1 = [word7, word11, word11]

word2 = [word8, word7]

word3 = [word9]

word4= [word10]

Comment: Can you give more context about what isn't working? What trouble shooting have you done, or errors are you facing?

Comment: I have tried, but it does not give the desired result. I think that the problem is with  the for loops. In a sense, I have to  for loop to all the lines of the datafile. But I am not doing it

Comment: What are the results you are getting? 'It doesn't work', does not give me any information about what your problem maybe. If I run your exact code on my computer right now and it works, where would that leave us? If you say it results in a certain string, 'resulting string'. It maybe easy to see that you have an escape character problem,or something.

Comment: The indices are incorrect: use 4 instead of 6, 7 instead of 8

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected it. But it still gives undesired result. The output is
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'aaaa': ["'word7", 'word10']})

Comment: So, what do you expect `my_dict` to be?

Comment: In this case

word1 = [word7, word11, word11]

word2 = [word8, word7]

word3 = [word9]

word4= [word10]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see. I believe your logic is fine until the inner for loop (`for elem in ...`). The solution is simpler: you don't need to have nested for loop, just use the `zip` function to pair every element in `a` (which I call `keys`) with corresponding elements in `b` (which I call `values`):

```
from collections import defaultdict

inputfile = open("file.txt","r")
my_dict = defaultdict(list)

for line in inputfile:
    line = line.split()
    keys = line[4].split("-")
    values = [v.strip("'") for v in line[7].split("-")]

    for k, v in zip(keys, values):
        my_dict[k].append(v)

for k, v in sorted(my_dict.items()):
    print('{} = {}'.format(k, v))
```

Output:

```
word1 = ['word7', 'word11', 'word11']  
word2 = ['word8', 'word7']             
word3 = ['word9']                      
word4 = ['word10']
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However, one of the words on the left may also contain a '. To remove it,  I have added     values_temp = line[7].replace("'","")

and the split on "-"

Comment: My bad. I missed that. Since the apostrophe could be anywhere, I revised my code to strip it from every values. I also revised the output so it looks cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

If the count of the strings `word` is the same in the left and the right, then i think you can use `re` module alongside with `defaultdict` and `zip` like this example:

```
import re 
from collections import defaultdict

final = defaultdict(list)

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for k in f:
        words = re.findall(r'(word\d+)[- ]', k.strip('\n'))
        groupped_words = zip(words[:int(len(words)/2)], words[int(len(words)/2):])
        for key, value in groupped_words:
            final[key] += [value]

for k, v in sorted(final.items()):
    print('{} : {}'.format(k, v))
```

output:

```
word1 : ['word7', 'word11', 'word11']
word2 : ['word8', 'word7']
word3 : ['word9']
word4 : ['word10']
```